# Mapping between two different Angular models

Tags: json, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to map Order.ts to OrderAction.ts, but getting the error Cannot ready property '0' of undefined.  This error is coming up when I try to map the Order properties to OrderAction properties.

Here is Order.ts:

`export class Order {
    OrderId: number;
    FunctionStatusList?: OrderFunctionStatus[];
}

export class OrderFunctionStatus {
    FunctionTypeCode: number;
    AvailableActions: OrderAvailableAction[];
}

export class OrderAvailableAction {
    ActionLabel: string;
    ActionValue: string;
}`

Here is OrderAction.ts:

```
export class OrderAction {
   FunctionTypeCode: number;
   SelectedAction: string;
   OrderList: AvailableAction[];
}

export class AvailableAction {
   OrderId: number;
   IsAvailableAction: boolean;
   AvailableActions?: OrderAvailableAction[];
 }
```

Here is the code that I wrote:

```
    orders: any[] = [];
    orderActionList: any[] = [];

    ngOnInit() {
        this.orders = this.orderService.getCheckedOrders();
        this.orders.forEach((order: Order, i) => {
            let orderAction: OrderAction = new OrderAction();
            orderAction.OrderList[i].OrderId = order.OrderId;
            orderAction.FunctionTypeCode = order.FunctionStatusList[i].FunctionTypeCode;
            orderAction.AvailableActions = order.FunctionStatusList[i].AvailableActions;
            orderAction.IsAvailableAction = order.FunctionStatusList[i].AvailableActions.length > 0 == true || false;
            this.orderActionList.push(orderAction);
        });
    }
```

Here is a sample of the Order.ts json:

```
    {
        "OrderId": "1",
        "FunctionStatusList": [{
            "FunctionTypeCode": "1",
            "AvailableActions": [{
                "ActionLabel": "1",
                "ActionValue": "1"
            }]
        }]
     }
```

Here is a sample of the OrderAction.ts json:

```
    {
    "FunctionTypeCode": "1",
    "SelectedAction: "1",
    "OrderList": [{
       "OrderId": "1",
       "IsAvailableActionsLoaded": "1",
       "AvailableActions": [{
          "ActionLabel": "1",
          "ActionValue": "1"
       }]
    }]
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where exactly you're getting the error, but I did the following and it converts `Order` to `OrderAction`: https://plnkr.co/edit/VEHAdk3qPRIFkEAU?preview

The meat of the code is this:

```
this.orders.forEach((order: Order, i) => {
    this.orderActions.push({
        FunctionTypeCode: order.FunctionStatusList[i].FunctionTypeCode,
        SelectedAction: null,
        OrderList: [
          {
            OrderId: order.OrderId,
            IsAvailableActionsLoaded:
              order.FunctionStatusList[i].AvailableActions.length > 0,
            AvailableActions: order.FunctionStatusList[i].AvailableActions,
          },
        ],
     });
});
```

I left `SelectedAction` as null because it was unclear how this value would be set.

Comment: I think one of the issues I have is that FunctionStatusList is an array of OrderFunctionStatus[] so looping through a list orders doesn't allow me to loop through of FunctionStatusList.  Any way we can discuss this in a room so I can show you the code that I'm trying?

Comment: So there can be multiple FunctionTypeCodes in an Order, but there is only one in OrderAction. Which one wins if they are different? As for AvailableActions you could collect these in a separate array and set that to AvailableActions after all FunctionStatusLists have been checked